# Issue regarding time complexity in Kahn's BFS algo for topological sort

Tags: java, graph, breadth-first-search

Everywhere it is written that the Kahn's BFS algo for topological sorting takes O(V+E) time complexity but if I break down its code , I realized while calculating in-degree of vertices, we are visiting a vertex multiple times so should not the TC be O(n^2) ?
Also in our while loop, we are visiting vertices more than once, so how is the TC still O(V+E) ?

Here is my code :

```
public static void sort(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList,int vertices){
        int[] inDegree=new int[vertices];
        for(int i=0;i<adjList.size();i++){
            for(int element : adjList.get(i)){
                inDegree[element]++;
            }
        }
        Queue<Integer> ourQueue=new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<vertices;i++){
            if(inDegree[i]==0){
                ourQueue.add(i);
            }
        }
        while(!ourQueue.isEmpty()){
            int poppedElement=ourQueue.poll();
            System.out.print(poppedElement+" ");
            for(int element : adjList.get(poppedElement)){
                inDegree[element]--;
                if(inDegree[element]==0){
                    ourQueue.add(element);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Everywhere in the internet" is a very ambiguous place - why not edit your question to add links? Are you sure your implementation is the exact same implementation "they" were referring to? Where is the link to prove it?

Comment: So i saw this question on https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/topological-sort/1# and I submitted this code there. It successfully worked there and expected time complexity there was O(V+E)

Answer (score 0):

In most graphs, `|E|` >> `|V|`. Let us use `|E| = m` and `|V| = n`. In a connected graph, you will have `m >= n-1`; in a complete graph, you will have `m = n*(n-1)`. So, for an "average" graph where `m` falls in between those extremes, `O(m+n)` looks very similar to `O(m)`, and to `O(n*n)`.

In your implementation, you are using an adjacency matrix with `n*n` cells; simply filling in that matrix is already `O(n*n)` - as is the vertex degree calculation that is performed in the 1st loop. If you were using an adjacency list instead, no loop would have been necessary (vertex degree could be calculated as the length of the adjacency list for each vertex, which is O(1) if using, say, `ArrayList``). So the implementation definitely impacts the run-time worst-case complexity.

You comment that an online programming puzzle site ranks your code as `O(V+E)`. However, the only practical way to find the complexity of a bit of code (absent humans or very complicated automated analysis, [doomed to fail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) in the general case) is to run it with a set of inputs of increasing size; and as I argue above, the difference between `O(V+E)` and  `O(V*V)` can be relatively small.

In short:

- The exact **graph representation** used for an algorithm can greatly impact its run-time complexity. Use adjacency lists for sparse graphs to save on time and memory.
- In a dense graph, `m` approaches `n*n`, and there is **no significant difference** between `O(V+E)`, `O(E)` and `O(V*V)`.
- Online programming quizzes cannot determine worst-case run-time complexity accurately. They can give you an estimate, but it is only an **empirical guess**, and not ground truth.